# Detect change in Observable, Angular4?

Tags: angular, observable, onchange, angularfire2

I have a `FirebaseObjectObservable` that will have a property called `game_state` that, when it changes, I want certain methods to trigger in my component, and my google-foo must be weak because I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

EDIT: I just wanted to update this since no one had a response related to the actual code problem, but LifeCycle Hooks are what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this is to have a service with constructor:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}
```

And a method:

```
getObject(key: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
    return this.db.object('/objects/' + key);
}
```

In your component:

```
constructor( private yourService: YourService){}

ngOnInit(){
      this.yourService.getObject(key).subscribe(item => {
      console.log(` Updated - call your methods here `);
      });
}
```

Hope that helps, it is pretty new to me but this method worked for my purposes. Would love to know if there is a better way.